# .NET Core app cannot connect to SQLServer but .Net 4.8 app Can. Why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, .net-core

There are dozens of posts about this, and I've read them all.

The SQL Server is on a remote machine.  I am connected to SQL Server through Server Explorer and SSMS.  I know the server is up, responsive, and allowing remote connections. 
[Image of VS Server Explorer connected to SQLServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37lqf.png)

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 app that is able to connect to the server instance as expected:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = 
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Server=192.168.10.11\vtdwprod;UID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;"))
            {
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully.");
            }
```

The same code in the .NET Core 3.1 app fails to connect and reports a network error.

```
using (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection(@"Server=192.168.10.11\vtdwprod;UID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;"))
           {
               con.Open();
               Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully.");
           }
```

I have tried System.Data and Microsoft.Data libraries on the .NET Core app and am not able to get connection to succeed.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Verify the port currently being used by the named instance from the SQL log and try connecting directly to the port, without using the instance name.  eg `Server=tcp:192.168.10.11,38721` on both .NET FX and .NET Core. Also ensure that the SQL Browser service is running and UDP port 1434 is not blocked.

Comment: ok, connecting with the tcp:<ip>,<port> worked.  Why is the .NET Core app not able to route my connection correctly based on the DNS host name, IP address, or instance name?

Comment: The resolution of an instance name to a port requires the SQL Browser service.  So it may be that neither can reach the browser, but .NET Framework is somehow flipping to Named Pipes, or has a Client Alias configured.  Or perhaps Browser is accessible only only IPv4 or only IPv6.

Comment: In any case to continue to use the port, set the instance to use a fixed port in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Nuget package System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.0

Then use

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck.  Installed System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.0 and changed to System.Data.  Same result.

Comment: You dont need to install this Nuget package because it`s for .NET Framework, so use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (more information about difference betwenn them here - [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) ) 

And I think after starting using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient you will have some another type of error, you can send it here and I will try to help

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you an answer without knowing what error you get. Try one of these

1. If the problem is that you get wrong password then this might be the problem.

   - Change the encoding of the file to **UTF-8**
2. Try to specify sql server port

   - Server=serveraddress,**1433**;Initial Catalog=DBName;UID=UserName;Password=pass;"